# How do I fix the "missing WiFi" issue with the Windows 10 upgrade?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, bluetooth

I've read a lot of suggested fixes for this. I've tried the Command Prompt *reg edit* fix to no avail.  I upgraded to Windows 10 back in August 2015. I've not paid attention to the absence of the Wi Fi display until now.

I show no adapter in Device Manager for my Network Connections, other than the Bluetooth and the Intel LAN. No WiFi icon in Task Bar.

I have a version of Windows 7 still on my computer (I can choose which version I want when I boot up the computer). There is no Network Adapter showing in Device Manager there either.

In the "Network & Internet" settings section, there is no WiFi option. The Troubleshooters are useless. They don't find any problem.

Anyone have a definitive fix for this issue? It seems to be a common one with the Windows 10 upgrade. Thanks in advance for your help.

mimart62